# Use gstreamer to record audio on android(with Qt5)

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, gstreamer

Trying to record audio on android with gstreamer(enable permission of audio record already), I prefer gstreamer but not the java api because there are more functions need to be added in the future, like
convert the audio to specific format(S16LE, channels=1, rate=16000 etc), encode as wav, separate video/audio and so on

The pipeline I am using are

```
openslessrc ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! fakesink
```

and

```
openslessrc ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! openslessink location=\"%1\"
```

But both of them give me error message

```
E IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -22
E AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -22
E libOpenSLES: android_audioRecorder_realize(0xcea58a00) error creating AudioRecord object; status -22
W libOpenSLES: Leaving Object::Realize (SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED)
```

Part of my .pro file

```
#plugins
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgsttypefindfunctions.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoconvert.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideorate.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoscale.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideofilter.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideotestsrc.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.a
#LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsoup.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstx264.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoparsersbad.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstandroidmedia.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.a

LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopensles.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioconvert.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudiotestsrc.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautoconvert.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioresample.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwavenc.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvoaacenc.a

LIBS += -lOpenSLES

#LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libavcodec.a


#plugin libs
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/liborc-0.4.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstgl-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgraphene-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libpng16.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libjpeg.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libx264.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.a
#LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstbadbase-1.0.a
#LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstbadvideo-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgsttag-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstphotography-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstcontroller-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.a
LIBS += -lEGL -lGLESv2

#gstreamer libs
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstbase-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgmodule-2.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libgobject-2.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libglib-2.0.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libffi.a
#LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libpcre.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libiconv.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libintl.a
LIBS += $${GSTREAMER_ROOT}/lib/libz.a
```

Initialization codes of gstreamer, in main.cpp

```
extern "C"
{

#include <gst/gst.h>

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(typefindfunctions);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videoconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videorate);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videoscale);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videofilter);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(autodetect);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videotestsrc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
//GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(soup);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(x264);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videoparsersbad);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(androidmedia);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(opengl);
//GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(qmlgl);

GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(opensles);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audiotestsrc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(autodetect);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(autoconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioresample);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(wavenc);
//GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(voaacenc);

#endif

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(coreelements);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(typefindfunctions);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videoconvert);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videorate);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videoscale);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videofilter);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(autodetect);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(playback);
    //GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(soup);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videotestsrc);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(x264);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videoparsersbad);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(androidmedia);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(opengl);
    //GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(qmlgl);

    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(opensles);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audioconvert);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audiotestsrc);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(autodetect);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(autoconvert);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(audioresample);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(playback);
    GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(wavenc);
    //GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(voaacenc);

    gst_debug_set_active(TRUE);
    gst_debug_set_default_threshold(GST_LEVEL_NONE);
#endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out a solution, problem is I did not register appropriate plugins, correct plugins should be

```
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coretracers);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(adder);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audiomixer);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audiorate);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioresample);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audiotestsrc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(typefindfunctions);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videoconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videorate);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videoscale);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videotestsrc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(volume);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(autodetect);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(videofilter);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(playback);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(audioparsers);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(auparse);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(multipart);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(wavenc);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(wavpack);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(wavparse);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(androidmedia);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(opengl);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(opensles);

GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(autoconvert);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(amrnb);
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(amrwbdec);
```

They are not the miminum list of the plugins and I don't have times to optimize it yet, I do not need to compile a libgstreamer_android.so to make them work on my phone, but they still work.